# Is is not possible to achieve average reward of more than 20-40 with simple Q-Learning

Tags: q-learning, rewards, open-ai, gym

I have implemented the simple Q-Learning based solution for AI-gym's Cartpole-v0.

However, despite changing hyper-parameters, and rechecking my code, I cannot get an average reward (N-running reward) of more than 30. My question is, is it not possible to get successful completion of Cartpole without using sophisticated algorithms such as Deep learning etc.?

I am glad to share my code, but I am sure no one would have time to check it.

[image: Sample reward outcomes]

PS. I know there are many implementations out there, but I have learned from them but I want to implement my own code for learning purpose and do not just want to copy-paste.

PSS (Edit): I have added the code in the answer to this question for reference.

Comment: The problem has continuous states. Probably the most critical part of your implementation using tabular Q learning is how you have approximated these states into discrete values. Could you add an explanation for that?

Comment: I discretize them into 50 discrete blocks as below

X_position = np.linspace(-2.4, 2.4, 50)
Velocity = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
Angle = np.linspace(-0.7295476, 0.7295476, 50)
Angular_vel = np.linspace(-5,5,50)

Comment: Then fitting any continuous state value into the respective discrete block isn't hard. For example if X is continuous state for location, then int(np.digitize(X, X_position)) can do the continuous to discrete conversion.

Comment: OK, so you have done that for all 4 state variables, giving a discrete state space size of ~ 6 million? Is your choice of 50 a hyper-parameter that you can easily change in your code?

Comment: Yes. It's a hyper-parameter that can be changed easily. For reference, I have added the code in the answer ( adding code to the question would make it difficult to read and understand).

Answer (score -1):

The code to my question is as below, for reference:

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Discretize the contiuous space
DISCRETE_POINTS = 50
X_position = np.linspace(-2.4, 2.4, DISCRETE_POINTS)
Velocity = np.linspace(-5, 5, DISCRETE_POINTS)
Angle = np.linspace(-0.7295476, 0.7295476, DISCRETE_POINTS)
Angular_vel = np.linspace(-5,5,DISCRETE_POINTS)

# Fit the instantnous state into any discrete box
def get_state(_state):
    
    X, X_bar, Angle_, Angle_bar = _state
    
    X = int(np.digitize(X, X_position))
    X_bar = int(np.digitize(X_bar, Velocity))
    Angle_ = int(np.digitize(Angle_, Angle))
    Angle_bar = int(np.digitize(Angle_bar, Angular_vel))
    
    return (X, X_bar, Angle_, Angle_bar)

def epsilon_greedy_action(s, epsilon):
    
    '''   Input argument: state 's' tuple in the form (4,0,1,0)    '''
    # if np.random.uniform() < epsilon:
    if np.random.random() > epsilon:
        a = env.action_space.sample()
    else: 
        _,a = find_maxQ_value(s)
    
    return a

def find_maxQ_value(state):
    '''
    Input argument: 
    state: should be a tuple of form (0,0,0,0) or (1,0,0,1) etc.
    
    Output argument:
    best_value: best q-value of the current state-action pair
    choosen_action: best action corresponding to current state. It depends on the best q-value
    '''
    
    for act_ in range(env.action_space.n):
        A = [Q[state,0], Q[state, 1]]
        best_value = np.max(A)
        choosen_action = np.argmax(A) 
    
    return best_value, choosen_action
 

def plotRunningAverage(totalrewards, N, n_avg):
  
    running_avg = np.empty(N)
    for t in range(N):
        running_avg[t] = np.mean(totalrewards[max(0, t-N):(t+1)])
    return running_avg 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    env = gym.make('CartPole-v0');
    
    EPISODES = 1000;
    no_actions = env.action_space.n
    
    # Hyper parameters
    alpha = 0.001 # Learning rate
    gamma = 0.99 #Discount Factor
    epsilon = 1 # For Epsilon-Greedy algorithm
    epsilon_decay_factor = 0.99;
    min_epsilon = 0.1;    

    states = []
    for i in range(len(X_position)):
        for j in range(len(Velocity)):
            for k in range(len(Angle)):
                for l in range(len(Angular_vel)):
                    states.append((i,j,k,l))
                    
    #Initialize Q-table : 
    # 1. We make the Q-table in form of a dictionary
    # 2. We initialize Q-table values as zero in this
    Q = {}
    for s in states:
        for n_a in range(no_actions):
            Q[s, n_a] = 0
    
    Running_reward = [];
    l_action_cnt = 0;
    r_action_cnt = 0;
    wrong_action =0;
    
    #Q-Learning agent episodes    
    for e in range(EPISODES):
            
        cn_state = env.reset()
        ds_state = get_state(cn_state)
        
        done = False
        ep_reward = 0
        ep_len = 0
         
        while not done:
            
            action = epsilon_greedy_action(ds_state, epsilon)   
            if action == 0:
                l_action_cnt+=1
            elif action == 1:
                r_action_cnt+=1;
            else:
                wrong_action+=1;
                
            cn_next_state, reward , done , ep_len = env.step(action)
            ep_reward += reward
            
            ds_next_state = get_state(cn_next_state)
            
            # Update the Q-table based on the action
            Val_Q_bar, _ = find_maxQ_value(ds_next_state);
             
            Q[ds_state, action] = (1-alpha)*Q[ds_state, action] + alpha*(reward + gamma*Val_Q_bar)
            
            ds_state = ds_next_state;
         
        Running_reward.append(ep_reward)
        
        if e%100 == 0:
            print('Episode : {}, Episode reward: {}, Epsilon: {}'.format(e, ep_reward, epsilon))
                
        if epsilon >= min_epsilon:
            epsilon*=epsilon_decay_factor;

plt.plot(Running_reward);
plt.xlabel('episodes')
plt.ylabel('episodic reward')
plt.grid('ON') 
running_avg = plotRunningAverage(Running_reward, EPISODES, 50)
plt.plot(running_avg);
plt.legend(['Episodic rewards', '50-Episode moving-average reward'])

print('The ratio of left to right action is : {}'.format(l_action_cnt/r_action_cnt))
```